# String comparing to constant with if-else statement. Skipping second if/else

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, compare

I seem to be running into an issue. While trying to get input based off of A.M./P.M. entry,my if else statement is having some sort of logic error. I've never really done this sort of thing (I'm a bit new to c++) so help would be appreciated.

```
cout << "What time was the dose administered? (Round to hour): ";
cin >> time;
cout << "A.M./P.M.? ";
cin >> ap;

cout << ap;

if (ap == "A.M.", "am"){
    ap = "A.M.";
}
else if (ap == "P.M.", "pm"){
    ap = "P.M.";
}
else { cout << "This is not a valid entry.";
}
```

"ap" is a string.
No matter what is entered, the result is "A.M."

Side note: Originally, it would only print "P.M." but both statements were orignally "if", when I changed it to "if else" it began printing "A.M." only.

Comment: what do you think (ap == "A.M.", "am") does? and what do you think (ap, "P.M.", "pm") resolves to?

Comment: You can't just make things up and expect them to work.

Answer (score 1):

This...

```
ap == "A.M.", "am"
```

...under the [rules of operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), is equivalent to...

```
"am"
```

...which in a boolean context undergoes standard conversion to `true` (via a non-0 pointer).

That's because the comma operator evaluates the sub-expression on its left - namely `ap == "A.M."` - and while any side-effects of that evaluation are enacted the actual value of the sub-expression is then discarded and the sub-expression on the right - namely `"am"` - is evaluated and used instead.

You should instead use:

```
if (ap == "A.M." || ap == "am")
```

(The C++ Standard allows the keyword "`or`" as an alternative to `||`, but famously Microsoft's compiler doesn't support it without an extra command-line argument, so in practice it's best avoided for portable code.)

Comment: Tony D has the write answer, I've done that many times before and I didn't even think of it. Thanks for the answer, Tony D!

Comment: @AceEbert: no worries... it's a pity C++ doesn't support a more concise and elegant way of writing this.... Cheers.